# tensorflow not training (only biases change)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to train a convolution network to output a number 0-100. But very quickly the model stops updating the weights, and only the biases in the Fully connected layers are changed. And I am unable to understand why.

Image of weights:
[image]

I've played around with different number of layers and so on, but I always run in to the same problem of only the FC biases changing.

This is the current code Im testing. Ive stripped away thing like dropout and such. Over fitting is not a concern at this moment. In fact, I would like to try and over fit the data just so I can see that my model learns anything

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


###################################################################################
############################# Read Data ###########################################

with tf.name_scope("READ_DATA"):

  def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)
    split_res = tf.string_split([key],'_')
    key = split_res.values[5]
    example = tf.image.decode_png(record_string)
    example = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(example, name=None)

    processed_example = resize_img(example)
    processed_example = reshape_img(processed_example)
    return processed_example, key


  def resize_img(imgg):
    return tf.image.resize_images(imgg,[102,525])

  def reshape_img(imgg):
    return tf.reshape(imgg,shape=[102,525,1])


  def input_pipeline( bsize=30, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        tf.train.match_filenames_once("./png_imgs/*.png"), num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)

    min_after_dequeue = bsize
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * 8

    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [example, label], batch_size=bsize, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return  example_batch, label_batch

  imb_batch1,label_batch1 = input_pipeline()

  single_img, single_lbl = input_pipeline(bsize=1)

############################# Read Data ###########################################
###################################################################################



# Parameters
#learning_rate = 0.0001
training_iters = 200000
batch_size = 30

# Network Parameters
n_input = 600*300*3 
n_classes = 1 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 102,525,1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)
learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) 


# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')


# Create model
def conv_net(x, dropout):

  # Convolution Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
      w = tf.get_variable('weights',[5,5,1,32], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
      b = tf.get_variable('biases',[32],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
      conv1 = conv2d(x,w,b)
      tf.summary.histogram('weights',w)
      tf.summary.histogram('biases',b)

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
      w = tf.get_variable('weights',[5,5,32,32], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
      b = tf.get_variable('biases',[32],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
      conv2 = conv2d(conv1,w,b)
      tf.summary.histogram('weights',w)
      tf.summary.histogram('biases',b)

    with tf.name_scope("Maxpool"):
      conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2,k=2)

    with tf.variable_scope('FC1') as scope:
      w = tf.get_variable('weights',[32*263*51,64], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
      b = tf.get_variable('biases',[64],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
      FC1 = tf.reshape(conv2,[-1,w.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
      FC1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(FC1,w),b)
      tf.summary.histogram('weights',w)
      tf.summary.histogram('biases',b)


    with tf.variable_scope('FC2') as scope:
      w = tf.get_variable('weights',[64,1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
      b = tf.get_variable('biases',[1],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
      FC2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(FC1,w),b)
      tf.summary.histogram('weights',w)
      tf.summary.histogram('biases',b)

    return FC2


# Construct model
pred = conv_net(x, keep_prob)

def cost():
  with tf.name_scope("Cost"):

    diff = tf.abs(tf.subtract(y,pred))
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(diff)
    print(cost)
  tf.summary.histogram('Label',y)
  tf.summary.histogram('predicted',pred)
  tf.summary.scalar('cost',cost)
  return cost

with tf.name_scope("Optimizer"):
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost())
 # optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost())


# Initializing the variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/tensorboard/log01")
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    step = 1
    l_rate= 0.1

    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        print("step: ",step)
        batch_x, batch_y = sess.run([imb_batch1,label_batch1])

        batch_y = batch_y.reshape(-1,1) 
        if step % 100 == 0 :
          l_rate = l_rate/5

        if l_rate < 0.000001 :
          l_rate= 0.000001

        if step > 20:
          _,sumry = sess.run([optimizer,merged], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                         keep_prob: dropout, learning_rate: l_rate})
          writer.add_summary(sumry,step)
        else :
          sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                         keep_prob: dropout, learning_rate: l_rate})


        step += 1

    print("Training Done!")



    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Is there a silly mistake somewhere in the code causing this?

Comment: My hunch: to me this could signal that the learning rate is too large. Since you are altering learning rate during training... maybe you could try with a constant LR and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @jjmontes, Yeah, Ive tried it with constant learning rates, large ones as well as small ones., but the problem still remains. My hope with starting out with rather large LR was for the the weights to become "shocked" by the large LR and thus make more aggressive changes, which later the finer LRs would adjust. But no such luck.

Comment: Have you tried switching the xavier_initializer() to a normal one?

Comment: @Dotan, yes, I have tried initializing it all to zeros (even though I understand that is not good), and also using random normal. But the same problem.  I tried this one with xavier just to start trying some tricks to see if it helped, but it did not.

Comment: @Simmeman have you solved your issue, if so please share your solution as i m too having this error .

Comment: @ashishkarel I did not manage to solve this. I left this approach and used a pretrained model and only changed the fully connected layers instead.

Comment: @ashishkarel did you manage to figure what your issue was (without using a pre-trained model)?

Comment: @mamafoku sorry mate couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a nonlinearity in your first fully-connected layer, so it adds no value compared to having just one fully-connected layer.